# What is the ideal way to retrieve image path from database in spring-rest API?

Tags: java, rest, api, spring-boot, image-processing

I am developing one spring rest API for customer. I am able to save the image in database in byte format and also able to download it. But, the android developer only needed the path of that image so that he can use that path to display the image on the app.

I am not sure how can get the path of image because it the data which i have saved it in database, as I am not saving that file on any folder.

Can anyone give me direction; what should be the right approach to this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provide a REST endpoint for the image file, delivered a ResponseEntity of MediaType Image, as opposed to JSON/XML or your traditional format.

```
import org.springframework.core.io.ByteArrayResource;
import org.springframework.core.io.Resource;
import org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;

@RequestMapping(path = "/images/{imageId}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
public ResponseEntity<Resource> getImage(@PathVariable Long imageId) {
    try {

        File file = imageService.getImage(imageId);

        Path path = Paths.get(file.getAbsolutePath());
        ByteArrayResource resource = new ByteArrayResource(Files.readAllBytes(path));

        return ResponseEntity.ok().contentLength(file.length()).contentType(MediaType.IMAGE_JPEG).body(resource);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new InternalServerException("Unable to generate image");
    }
}
```

Comment: Is it retrieve the path of image or the complete image (in byte) from database?

Comment: For the developer, you'd give them the REST endpoint, i.e. `localhost:8080/foo-app/images/1`, for your spring boot app, you can either create a file from bytes on server or send bytes directly without file creation through the ResponseEntity.

Comment: Yeah, I want to send the image to developer when he hit this url "localhost:8080/foo-app/images/1". But since the image is in byte and we can only send the JSON data then how can we display jpg file?

Comment: Examine the `return` statement. When they hit that endpoint, they get data with content-type as a JPEG. You can send non-JSON through REST endpoints as long as you mark its content type.

Comment: Can you please show me the imports of above example and also the getAbsolutePath() method? I am getting errors.

Comment: I've added imports in the code. Everything should be core spring framework.